# Does StringTemplate work with Struts?

Tags: templates, struts, stringtemplate

I would like to use a template engine in my struts web application. Therefore I would like to use StringTemplate, but have no idea how to implement in Struts.

Comment: Tip: Get away from struts nearly every f/work now available is better. They all do a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into how this would work myself.  It looks like Harry Karadimas has put together some code for Struts 1.3 [here](http://www.stringtemplate.org/share/1229347891527/st_struts_adapter_with_demo.0.2.zip).

See usage.html in the /doc directory.